# How to select img tag inside the current div with jsoup

Tags: javascript, android, html, image, jsoup

I try to parse web page using the `jsoup`, where I select element using the `select` method of the `jsoup`. I want to next element in the `div`.

My page source is

```
<a class="class" href="href" title="title">
 <img src="src" alt="alt"/>
</a>
```

I select the class element using the

```
Elements element = doc.select(".class");
```

I got result in the `element` but I want to get image src also. How can I get it?

Comment: you want to get the image data itself of just the url?

Comment: I want the image url only i.e src of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an attribute's value with the following method: `attr(String key)`

Example:

```
// Selects the first instance of img within .class
Element element = doc.select(".class img").first();

// Gets the value of the element's src 
String src = element.attr("src");
```